# Ansible - how to execute powershell win_command as elevated privilege

Tags: ansible

Looking for guidance how to execute powershell win_command with elevated privilege.

My playbook example:

```
    ---
- name: Run powershell script
  hosts: win
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: windows test command
      win_command: powershell.exe -
      args: 
        stdin: ipconfig >> c:\ipconfig.txt
```

This works fine since it doesnt need elevated privilege, but if I try something that requires runas administrator I cannot seem to figure out, tried adding 'become_method: runas'  no luck ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should work this way:

```
- name: Run powershell script
  hosts: win
  gather_facts: false
  become_method: runas

  vars:
    ansible_become_password: "{{ password }}"

  tasks:
    - win_command: powershell.exe -
      args: 
        stdin: ipconfig >> c:\ipconfig.txt
      become: yes
      become_user: Administrator
```

Comment: Just to note, connecting (over winrm, in my case) as Administrator in the first place is not enough. The `become: yes` is still needed for some actions, such as installing KB3035131 on Windows 2012 (https://github.com/chocolatey-community/chocolatey-coreteampackages/issues/1002)