# Ansible playbook or role to execute a particular task on different host while rest on inventory_host

Tags: ansible

Here is my requirement.

I am trying to create a playbook to perform server patching. In my ansible play I planned to implement a task to take back-up of the inventory_host (linux) before applying patches or updates through veeambackup. In case there is issue with patch activity it will be easy to restore. The veeam-backup runs on a different server (windows) through veaam-backup-replication server, thus this task shall run on windows. For this I tried below.

```
  - name: Include Veeam activities role
  include_role:
    name: veeam_activities
    apply:
      delegate_to: "{{ veeam_server }}"         
  vars:
    veeam_action: backup
    veeam_variables: "{{ veeam_variables }}"
    ansible_user: "{{ veeam_username }}"
    ansible_password: "{{ veeam_password }}"
    ansible_winrm_transport: ntlm
    ansible_connection: winrm
    ansible_ssh_port: 5986
    ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore 
  
  - name: Install available updates
  yum:
    name: '*'
    state: latest
  register: update_task
```

The task that runs in veeam_activities role is power-shell and due variables I see a degree of conflict. Example error I see is `msg: The powershell shell family is incompatible with the sudo become plugin`.

Can someone point me to right method to delegate tasks to run on different hosts in this type of cross OS and hosts have different login credentials.

Note: I tried to include `become: no` in `vars:` but no luck.

Comment: This should be helpful (Seems similar issue): https://stackoverflow.com/a/51076890/8188682

Comment: I don't understand your problem nor what you are exactly trying to achieve. It seems to me that all the variables in your first task should be in your inventory and that you should target the correct groups in different plays inside the same playbook. Regarding your last note, `become: no` should not be in `vars:` section but set directly as a task option (same level as `vars:` or `name:`) But I have once again no idea what you are trying to achieve with that. Since `sudo` is not supported by windows, you should set the correct `become_method` for those hosts in your inventory.

Comment: Dear @Zeitounator,

The play book runs on host-1 (inventory_host) but a task in playbook should run on a different host which is not inventory_host that is a dependency in the steps/tasks to run. In above case "Include Veeam activities role" are delegated to `veeam_server`  and need to pass veeam_server credentials but since the ansible variables are  passed between roles I see the conflict. My question is can that be handled? 
Eg: I do not want to pass `become: yes` from main playbook to task "Include Veeam activities role" delegated to "veeam_server".

Comment: Please don't add necessary information in comment. [edit] your question and make it a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer, in apply declarative when I pass become_method and become_user the veeam_activities role ran fine on windows host while rest of tasks run on inventory_host. Thus, delegate and become attributes played role when delegating work to different host (cross OS scenario).

```
- name: Trigger Veeam Backup
  include_role:
    name: veeam_activities
    apply:
      delegate_to: "{{ veeam_server }}"
      become_method: runas 
      become_user: Administrator       
  vars:
    veeam_action: backup
    ansible_user: "{{ veeam_username }}"
    ansible_password: "{{ veeam_password }}"
    ansible_winrm_transport: ntlm
    ansible_connection: winrm
    ansible_ssh_port: 5986
    ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore  
  when: update_check.results | length > 0
```